# Combining json output from multiple foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have php script which returns video streams as output. Output contains multiple unique streams.

I am trying to encode output into json but because of multiple foreach loop its not giving proper output

Code :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["id"]))
    $id = $_GET["id"];
$temp = explode("=",$id);
$link=end($temp);

parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$link), $video_data);
$streams = $video_data['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
$streams = explode(',',$streams);

$arr = array(); 

foreach ($streams as $streamdata) {
    parse_str($streamdata,$streamdata);
    foreach ($streamdata as $key => $value) {
        $myObj->$key = $value;
    }
    $arr = $myObj;
}

echo json_encode(array("streams"=>$arr));
?>
```

Above code will return only last stream/item from output.

Output :

```
{
   "streams":{
      "quality":"small",
      "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\"",
      "itag":"17",
      "url":"video_link"
    }
}
```

If i put `echo json_encode(array("streams"=>$arr));` inside upper foreach loop.
It will return all streams with multiple root nodes, and its not acceptable.
I need only one root node which contains all steams.

Output :

```
{
     "streams":{
      "type":"video\/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2\"",
      "itag":"22",
      "url":"video_link",
      "quality":"hd720"
    }
    }{
    "streams":{
      "type":"video\/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\"",
      "itag":"43",
      "url":"video_link",
      "quality":"medium"
    }
    }{
    "streams":{
      "type":"video\/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2\"",
      "itag":"18",
      "url":"video_link",
      "quality":"medium"
    }
    }{
    "streams":{
      "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\"",
      "itag":"36",
      "url":"video_link",
      "quality":"small"
    }
    }{
    "streams":{
      "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\"",
      "itag":"17",
      "url":"video_link",
      "quality":"small"
    }
}
```

Desired output will be :

```
{
  "streams":[
  {
     "quality":"hd720",
     "itag":"44",
     "url":"video_link",
     "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  {
     "quality":"medium",
     "itag":"",
     "url":"video_link",
     "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  {
     "quality":"medium",
     "itag":"17",
     "url":"video_link",
     "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  {
     "quality":"medium",
     "itag":"17",
     "url":"video_link",
     "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  {
     "quality":"small",
     "itag":"17",
     "url":"video_link",
     "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\""
  },
  {
     "quality":"small",
     "itag":"17",
     "url":"video_link",
     "type":"video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\""
  }

 ]
  }
```

Is there any way to combing multiple root nodes or get json output with all streams.

Note :

- Outer foreach loop iterates 5 times in script lifetime
- Inner foreach loop iterates 4 times per each outer foreach loop in script lifetime

Please help me with this as i am new to php. TIA !!!

Comment: Please give an example of your desired output. The output provided in answer contains invalid JSON data and it is not clear if you mentioned it as the desired output, or the output currently generated by your code (which you don't want)

Comment: Please provide an example of `$video_data` and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this and got the output.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
    $id = $_GET["id"];
$temp = explode("=",$id);
$link=end($temp);

parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$link), $video_data);
$streams = $video_data['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
$streams = explode(',',$streams);

$arr = array(); 

foreach ($streams as $streamdata) {
    parse_str($streamdata,$streamdata);
    $myObj = new stdClass();
    foreach ($streamdata as $key => $value) {
        $myObj->$key = $value;
    }
    array_push($arr, $myObj);
}


print_r (json_encode(array("streams"=>$arr)));
?>
```

output:

```
{
    "streams": [{
            "itag": "22",
            "url": "https:\/\/r5---sn-q4fl6nlz.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?expire=1503278582&mm=31&mv=m&pl=14&mt=1503256900&ms=au&ei=luGZWY6yCc-I-wOk15GgAQ&signature=703194A7AAF91601C8B1A3D674CDEE89D9B7F7D4.489762A45FA4A3A72D00974427199FCFF1538CF9&source=youtube&beids=%5B9466594%5D&mn=sn-q4fl6nlz&requiressl=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=997500&pcm2=yes&lmt=1502949906234234&dur=250.938&itag=22&ip=172.251.185.232&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ratebypass=yes&id=o-AIo4CAPPPE9wPzwlmOhlF16F8YLqOYKrKwH0STEOsWbH&key=yt6",
            "type": "video\/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2\"",
            "quality": "hd720"
        }, {
            "itag": "43",
            "url": "https:\/\/r5---sn-q4fl6nlz.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?expire=1503278582&mm=31&mv=m&pl=14&mt=1503256900&ms=au&ei=luGZWY6yCc-I-wOk15GgAQ&signature=4333D8109A90B3DC6844C6A6930A8558ECCC2A05.B736A90E09E2A47A4B3E1630CDD260099A15E17C&source=youtube&beids=%5B9466594%5D&mn=sn-q4fl6nlz&requiressl=yes&clen=25853304&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=997500&pcm2=yes&lmt=1502953964372465&dur=0.000&itag=43&mime=video%2Fwebm&ip=172.251.185.232&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ratebypass=yes&id=o-AIo4CAPPPE9wPzwlmOhlF16F8YLqOYKrKwH0STEOsWbH&gir=yes&key=yt6",
            "type": "video\/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\"",
            "quality": "medium"
        }, {
            "itag": "18",
            "url": "https:\/\/r5---sn-q4fl6nlz.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?expire=1503278582&mm=31&mv=m&pl=14&mt=1503256900&ms=au&ei=luGZWY6yCc-I-wOk15GgAQ&signature=2F70C59BD7F8F63DCEFA2935882935245A04C40B.E3D4DA76837E3DC74B795B17982796C11BCEBF53&source=youtube&beids=%5B9466594%5D&mn=sn-q4fl6nlz&requiressl=yes&clen=18940088&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=997500&pcm2=yes&lmt=1502949691460473&dur=250.938&itag=18&mime=video%2Fmp4&ip=172.251.185.232&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ratebypass=yes&id=o-AIo4CAPPPE9wPzwlmOhlF16F8YLqOYKrKwH0STEOsWbH&gir=yes&key=yt6",
            "type": "video\/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2\"",
            "quality": "medium"
        }, {
            "itag": "36",
            "url": "https:\/\/r5---sn-q4fl6nlz.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?expire=1503278582&mm=31&mv=m&pl=14&mt=1503256900&ms=au&ei=luGZWY6yCc-I-wOk15GgAQ&signature=914720619C03249F8A94B02CA36F95D2CD8A50E7.8C06516CEFD9667BEEA2950F63FEDBF701E85D69&source=youtube&beids=%5B9466594%5D&mn=sn-q4fl6nlz&requiressl=yes&clen=6819898&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=997500&pcm2=yes&lmt=1502949683841137&dur=250.961&itag=36&mime=video%2F3gpp&ip=172.251.185.232&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&id=o-AIo4CAPPPE9wPzwlmOhlF16F8YLqOYKrKwH0STEOsWbH&gir=yes&key=yt6",
            "type": "video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\"",
            "quality": "small"
        }, {
            "itag": "17",
            "url": "https:\/\/r5---sn-q4fl6nlz.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?expire=1503278582&mm=31&mv=m&pl=14&mt=1503256900&ms=au&ei=luGZWY6yCc-I-wOk15GgAQ&signature=A2741E73F8FF9500D84A3A2E69F84536F7168B38.BB6575A1C38784D6841F2D8788FDEE38D4F0DA2B&source=youtube&beids=%5B9466594%5D&mn=sn-q4fl6nlz&requiressl=yes&clen=2446985&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=997500&pcm2=yes&lmt=1502949684640176&dur=250.961&itag=17&mime=video%2F3gpp&ip=172.251.185.232&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&id=o-AIo4CAPPPE9wPzwlmOhlF16F8YLqOYKrKwH0STEOsWbH&gir=yes&key=yt6",
            "type": "video\/3gpp; codecs=\"mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2\"",
            "quality": "small"
        }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i wanted !!

Answer (score 0):

This should give the desired output:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["id"]))
    $id = $_GET["id"];
$temp = explode("=",$id);
$link=end($temp);

parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$link), $video_data);
$streams = $video_data['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
$streams = explode(',',$streams);

$arr = array(); 

foreach ($streams as $streamdata) {
    parse_str($streamdata,$streamdata);
    foreach ($streamdata as $key => $value) {
        $arr[] = [$key => $streamdata[$key]]
    }
}

echo json_encode(array("streams"=>$arr));
?>
```

Comment: I think this solution would not produce the output requested in the description.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks but it will only output values without keys

Comment: @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan Nope. Still getting only last stream as output

Comment: Now? I not sure about how you files looks like.

Comment: @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan Thanks,Output is correct now but not in the format which i have specified in my question. Please can you output json format as i specified. It will be very helpful

Comment: How is the output now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152400/discussion-between-xamdev-and-sebastian-corneliu-virlan).